# async await returning [object Promise] in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await

I' using async function like this:

```
methods:{
    async getUser(id)
    { 
 
      const header = '........';
        let responses=await axios.get(`/api/backend/method/${id}` , {headers: header});
      return responses.data.name; 

    },
```

calling it on load of td in a loop, like this

```
<td v-html="getUser(request.id)"></td>
```

now in my td i get `[object Promise]` but in this variable `responses.data.name` there is name, i want to return that name. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're not calling `getUser` with `await`, so the returned value is its Promise.

Comment: I would instead suggest you adjust the method to affect `data`, then invoke the method inside some lifecycle hook, finally the template simply reads from `data`   -  or just use vuex (with module `init`)

Answer (score 1):

```js
data() {
    return {
    // .... other vars
    usernames: {},
    requests: [],
    };
},
methods:{
    afterRequestLoaded() {
        this.requests.forEach((request) => this.loadusername(request.id);
    },
    async loadusername(id)
    { 
 
      const header = '........';
        let responses=await axios.get(`/api/backend/method/${id}` , {headers: header});
        this.usernames[id] = responses.data.name; 
    },
```

```html
<tr v-for="request in requests">
   <td v-text="usernames[request.id]"></td>
</tr>
```

Note that `afterRequestLoaded` function should be executed when `requests` array is populated. perhaps by another api call.